# jQuery validator custom method undefined *sometimes*

Tags: jquery, webpack, jquery-validate, sentry

I've occasionally been getting a weird error reported in Sentry that one of our custom jQuery validator methods is undefined. However, this *should* be impossible - we're using webpack to bundle our scripts, and the custom methods are bundled in the same bundle as both jQuery and validator.

This is a very uncommon error, and 75% of devices that trigger it are iPad. I'd like to ignore it but it keeps bugging me. How can this possibly happen?

Here are the specifics...

- The custom method is called "NoPOBoxes"
- The specific error reported by Sentry is: "Cannot read property 'call' of undefined.  Exception occurred when checking element BillAddress2, check the 'NoPOBoxes' method."
- The line that causes the error is: `result = $.validator.methods[ method ].call( this, val, element, rule.parameters );`

Webpack is creating two bundles for us, a main and a sub:

webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        "main": [ "./dev/config/main.js" ],
        "sub": [ "./dev/config/sub.js" ]
....
```

main.js (relevant portion):

```
require('jquery');
require("../source/jQueryPlugins/Validator/1.17.0");
require("../source/jquery.validate.1.17.0.CustomMethods");
```

Everything else is pretty standard, sub.js is responsible for setting up the validator and all the rules etc. These scripts (main.js and sub.js) are included at the bottom of the page, like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/includes/bundles/dist/main.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/includes/bundles/dist/sub.js"></script>
```

Also, sub.js has one last fail-safe. Before it does anything, it checks to see if jQuery is defined. So, being that jQuery, validator, and our custom validator methods are all defined in main.js - this *should* mean that if jQuery is defined, validator and validator's custom methods are defined.

```
(function() {
    var jQueryLoading = setInterval(function() {
        if (typeof($) === "function") {
            clearInterval(jQueryLoading);
            $(document).ready(function(){
                // do stuff
            });
        }
    }, 100);
})();
```

Can anyone see if I'm missing something?